# Adding omnifaces project gives incorrect url at redirect

Tags: jsf, primefaces, glassfish, omnifaces

Using omnifaces 1.6 in a jsf project with primefaces 3.5 on glassfish 3.1.2

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("localhost/my-project/views/index.jsf");
```

Using this code will redirect to a page with url `localhost/my-project/`
This issue is when omnifaces is added without omnifaces the function works correctly with no problem

Comment: This is not the default behavior. Did you change anything in `web.xml` or `faces-config.xml`? Perhaps something related to FacesViews?

Comment: in my web.xml i am using auth-method FORM where when opening index.jsf a redirect to login page is opened and at preRenderView of the index.jsf page i am calling this line of code `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("localhost/my-project/views/index.jsf");` where it redirects me to localhost/my-project/ instead of index.jsf where whithout omnifaces the redirect url is correct

Comment: An SSCCE in flavor of a WAR would be helpful. I can at least tell that the given redirect URL is in first place indeed strange as indicated by the answer of unwichtich.

Comment: may be strange but how it would be that without the omniface jar file the redirect is correct while adding the jar file the redirect changes

Comment: As indicated, I can't answer that until I see the SSCCE in flavor of a WAR.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you expect but when you redirect to `localhost/my-project/` then a redirect to a page with url `localhost/my-project/` seems like the correct behaviour.

Maybe you missed the port (e.g. redirect to `localhost:8080/my-project/`) but in general it is not intended to redirect to a URL containing localhost but to a specific page (e.g. redirect to `index.jsf` or `index.xhtml`). You don't even need the webapp context (i.e. `my-project`), you can just redirect to your "main page" like this:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("home.xhtml");
```